# Java взаимодействие с USB

Tags: java, usb

Есть приложение написанное на JAVA в intellij IDEA под Windows 64. Необходимо сделать usb ключ.
То есть приложение должно считывать PID и VID. И если они не соответствуют, приложение закрывается. Как понимаю необходимы внешние библиотеки для java. 
Или же вообще нет смысла пытаться сделать это в java?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте готовые решения. Мы используем Sentinel (https://safenet-sentinel.ru/) у них есть SDK который обеспечивает все манипуляции. 
Если же у вас свое апаратное решение, то можно написать *.dll/*.so библиотеку и вызывать ее из JNA или при помощи JNI.